# spring data mongodb method query

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

Suppose my document contains two field - `from` and `to`. I want to fetch all the documents whose `from` is `lessThanEqual` the provided value and `to` is greaterthanEqual the provided value.
the way I can do that is

`List<T> findAllByFromLessThanEqualAndToGreaterThanEqual(Integer from, Integer to)`

I am using method query way to achieve it.

Now suppose I have a list of Integer, is there any efficient way to fetch the records in single query.

Something like instead of iterating over the list of Integer and firing the query again and again

```
List<T> list = someIntList
                  .stream()
                  .map(someInt -> someRepository.findAllByFromLessThanEqualAndToGreaterThanEqual(someInt, someInt))
                  .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above way will hit the database again and again, so is there any more efficient way to achieve it in a single query.

Comment: @JB Nizet any idea?

Comment: @BalusC anything you can help with in this?